# plotting tick text above the axis

Tags: d3.js, graph

I am using d3 v4 for ploting the graph. And currently the tick text on the x-axis is coming below the axis. and I want that text on above the axis.

```
//Set the Xaxis scale Range
        let x = scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
        let x_axis = axisBottom(x);

x.domain(extent(graphData, function (d) {
            return d.weeks;
        }));

g.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(axisBottom(x).ticks(5)).attr("transform", "translate(0, 120)");
```

so can you help me how to put the tick text above the x-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ticks on top of the axis, you should use `axisTop`, instead of `axisBottom`.

The names are pretty easy to understand and the API is very clear:

> - d3.axisTop(scale): In this orientation, ticks are drawn **above** the horizontal domain path.
> - d3.axisBottom(scale):  In this orientation, ticks are drawn **below**
>   the horizontal domain path. (emphases mine)

Here is a demo, the first axis uses `axisTop`, and the second one, below, uses `axisBottom`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([20, 280]);
var xAxisTop = d3.axisTop(x)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
var xAxisBottom = d3.axisBottom(x)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,100)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```